# Unable to set custom header values in jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The below hardcoded header works fine..

```
$.ajax({
  type: "post",
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json",
  **headers:{'myHeader':'123'}**,
```

But I want this to be dynamically framed like below

```
var headerparam='';    
if(headername != '' && headervalue != ''){
  headerparam = "{\'"+headername+"\':\'"+headervalue+"\'}";
}
```

And tried to input this headerparam variable in the ajax

```
$.ajax({
  type: "post",
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json",  
  **headers: headerparam,**
```

But this shows the header value in the multi line format as shown below while inspecting it in the developer tools.

> 0:{
>   1:'
>   10:'
>   11:e
>   12:w
>   13:r
>   14:w
>   15:e
>   16:r
>   17:w
>   18:e
>   19:'
>   2:w
>   20:}
>   3:e
>   4:r
>   5:w
>   6:e
>   7:r
>   8:'
>   9::
>   Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01

Please suggest how to pass the value dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `headers` values as a plain object

```
var headerparam = {};    
if(headername != '' && headervalue != ''){
  headerparam[headername] = headervalue;
}
```

or use valid `JSON` to parse to a JavaScript object

```
var headerparam = "";    
if(headername != '' && headervalue != ''){
  headerparam = `{"${headername}":"${headervalue}"}`
}
```

```
headers:JSON.parse(headerparam)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing headers as a string and not an object:

`headerparam = "{\'"+headername+"\':\'"+headervalue+"\'}"; 
//This is a string because it is wrapped in quotes`

Also, I believe you do not need to `\'` escape your single quotes.

Comment: Thanks. This worked fine with the format you mentioned..
headerparam = '{"'+headername+'":"'+headervalue+'"}';
and in the ajax call,
headers:JSON.parse(headerparam),